# Call function from outside master view model in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-3.2

I've seen [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643940/knockout-js-access-viewmodel-in-javascript-function-outside-viewmodels-scope) [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047660/calling-function-in-knockout-js-from-outside-view-model) about it, but none of them using exactly the same structure as me.

I am using multiple view models and I deal with it by creating a MasterModel function which later on I pass as an argument to `applyBindings`.

Basically something like this:

```
var MasterModel = function(){
    this.user = new UserViewModel();
    this.department = new DepartmentViewModel();
}

ko.applyBindings(MasterModel);
```

Now, I would like to be able to access from Javascript to a function inside one of my view models and I'm having troubles with it.

I managed to call the viewmodel function if I change the `applyBindings` to this:

```
var mm = new MasterModel();
ko.applyBindings(mm);

mm.user.sayHi();
```

But then I found out things like the following stop working:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: department.list()">
     <li data-bind="text: department.getDemo($data)"></li>
</ul>
```

> Message: department is not defined

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/imac/qWmat/107/)

And as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/imac/qWmat/108/), it works perfectly when using `ko.applyBindings(MasterModel);`

Any solution for this?

Comment: to make view cleaner use `with` in such cases . very helpful

Comment: That doesn't solve much when you are inside nested elements like `foreach`

Comment: humm i believe you misunderstood what i am saying . check this http://jsfiddle.net/qWmat/111/ . i am just trying to say use `with` not to replace in place of `foreach` . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point Knockout in the right direction in order to use `department`:

```
<li data-bind="text: $root.department.getDemo($data)"></li>
```

When you're inside a `foreach` loop, the scope is the item you're currently iterating on, and this item (obviously) doesn't have the `department` property.

You need to use `$root` to tell Knockout that it's the `department` defined on the root view-model you're referring to.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWmat/110/) and [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Comment: What about `$parent`? Why can't I use it?

Comment: In your particular case, you can use `$parent` as well. But, if you'll ever refactor your model to have more than one level of nesting `$parent` would break. You better use `$root` since you already know it's defined at the root of your view-model.

Comment: The bad thing of it is that it starts to look very verbose. The `$parent` doesn't work at all btw: http://jsfiddle.net/imac/qWmat/112/

Comment: @Alvaro `$parent` will work check the comment to you post . cheers

Answer (score 1):

Inside the foreach, you don't have direct access to `department` because foreach introduces its own binding context. You can use `$root` or `$parent` to access your MasterModel:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: department.list()">
   <li data-bind="text: $parent.department.getDemo($data)"></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qWmat/109/

> A binding context is an object that holds data that you can reference from your bindings. While applying bindings, Knockout automatically creates and manages a hierarchy of binding contexts. The root level of the hierarchy refers to the viewModel parameter you supplied to ko.applyBindings(viewModel). Then, each time you use a control flow binding such as with or foreach, that creates a child binding context that refers to the nested view model data.

[Read more](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use `$parent.department.getDemo($data)` instead of just `$parent.getDemo($data)` as you are already inside a department loop.

Comment: You're not inside a department loop, you're looping over the list.